# Remove the edmx file - keep only POCO entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to get rid of the big messy edmx file which has caused me nothing but pain when merging in svn.

I would like to move towards code first. For this, ideally I would generate the classes automatically based on the current edmx, then remove the edmx file completely.

I won't need a designer after that, I'll add columns and relations by hand.

How would you go about obtaining this? Would the new ef 4.2(?) be a better fit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually generated the .cs files from the edmx changing the generator to "ADO.NET DbContext Generator" from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2 .

Then added primary and foreign keys as they weren't generated (I am using a mysql db if it makes any differences).

Then I had to change a ton of queries because if before you could do :

```
from x in context.Table1
from y in context.Table2
where x.id = y.xid
```

and would translate to a join, this no longer works !

Quite a bit to change but eventually it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) 
to generate the POCOs from your existing Database.

> **Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1** 
>   Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.

After you have your POCOs and you Context generated, you dont need the
edmx file anymore.

Comment: That is not true. If you use context generated by POCO generator you still need EDMX because at compile time it is decomposed to SSDL, MSL and CSDL files which are included as resources to your assembly. At runtime these files are used to configure mapping (they are referenced in connection string).